# Return 404 in Angular application running in Html 5 mode

Tags: angularjs, html, nginx, http-status-code-404, prerender

We have an angular application running in HTML 5 mode. In line with Angular HTML 5 guidelines, the web server Nginx is configured to return index.html for any uri as follows:

```
 location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Now, this is a public (WWW) website that is being crawled by the Google bot regularly. In the Google Webmaster console, we can see some invalid urls that have been crawled.

Since index.html is returned for any url, the crawler does not get a 404 response code. The result is that all the invalid urls are treated as duplicate content (since they all have home page content).

We are using [Prerender](http://prerender.io) to serve static versions of our webpages.

Is there any way to return a 404 error in case the url does not match in Angular 
?

Comment: One thing you could do to avoid duplicate content and still get the index page for every missing resource would be to return a 302 FOUND or 301 MOVED PERMANENTLY instead and relocating ("Location" header) to "the one" index.html